# JpaRepository find User with Role in list of roles

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring` with `Hibernate` and `JpaRepository` as database repository.

I have two classes for user storage:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserRole> roles;
}

@Entity
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
}

public enum Role {
    ADMIN,
    MEMBER;
    /* some others in the future */
}
```

As you can see `User` can have multiple roles assigned. So `user1` can have `ADMIN` and `MEMBER` roles and `user2` only `MEMBER` role.

I would like to user with `ADMIN` role (among others) could list all users in database (`JpaRepository` `findAll()` method is enough) but user with only `MEMBER` role could list only users with `MEMBER` role.

How to write method in `JpaRepository` to achieve that? I tried some below but it's not working:

```
List<User> findByRoles_RoleIn(Collection<Role> roles);
```

or

```
List<User> findByRoles_Role(Role role);
```

Maybe some custom `@Query`?

Answer (score 5):

If you can go for a custom query then try following:

```
@Query( "select u from User u inner join u.roles r where r.role in :roles" )
List<User> findBySpecificRoles(@Param("roles") List<Role> roles);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't really work like it should. I get duplicated entries for every user when he has multiple roles that fit to List<Role>. How to fix it?

Comment: You need to add 'distinct' after select in that case

Comment: ok 'distinct' helped with that but I found another issue and I don't think that such simple is enough. When I pass MEMBER as argument I should get list with users that has only MEMBER role, now I get users with MEMBER and ADMIN roles. I tried reverse Query to "[...] not in :roles" and pass ADMIN as argument but it didn't work either.

Comment: try to put param in brackets.. (:roles)

Comment: any luck with testing?

Comment: @user3626048 were you able to find the solution for this issue? Kindly can you mention it here? I am in the same situation at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is if you wish not to use @query

Query by role object

```
List<User> findByRoles_(Role role);
```

Query by role object id

```
List<User> findByRoles_Id(Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom jpql query for this case. And implement two methods with custom query one for admin and one for simple users.
Something like

`@Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r.role=:rolename")`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve the users with list of role names in JPA, you can add below method in the repository.

```
List<User> findByRoles_NameIn(List<String> roles);
```